# undefined reference to `sigsetjmp' in rust static library musl build with openssl

Tags: c++, linux, rust, openssl, musl

The previous question that gives a bit of background to this one:
[undefined reference to symbol 'clock_gettime@@GLIBC_2.4 In rust static library for musl target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76965154/undefined-reference-to-symbol-clock-gettimeglibc-2-4-in-rust-static-library-f)

Now when compiling the c++ program i get the error:

```
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/inkbox-toreader/libs/Libretranslate-rs-to-cpp/lib//libLibretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a(armcap.o): in function `OPENSSL_cpuid_setup':
armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0xa2): undefined reference to `sigsetjmp'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0xae): undefined reference to `sigsetjmp'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0xf4): undefined reference to `sigsetjmp'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0x100): undefined reference to `sigsetjmp'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0x10c): undefined reference to `sigsetjmp'
/mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/compiled-binaries/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/11.2.0/../../../../arm-kobo-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld.bfd: /mnt/HDD/Project/inkbox-build/inkbox/inkbox-toreader/libs/Libretranslate-rs-to-cpp/lib//libLibretranslate_rs_to_cpp.a(armcap.o):armcap.c:(.text.startup.OPENSSL_cpuid_setup+0x118): more undefined references to `sigsetjmp' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:505: build/inkbox] Error 1
```

The only thing i could find was:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59188

Specifically from there:

```
glibc (at least the 2.17 I have around) doesn't have sigsetjmp function at all,
it only conditionally has sigsetjmp as a macro
```

So what do I do with that? I don't even have such an old GLIBC

I was able to compile the rust library even with zig with a local not vendored openssl build:

```
OPENSSL_DIR=/home/build/inkbox/openssl/ cargo zigbuild --target armv7-unknown-linux-musleabihf
```

but the issue remains the same

Comment: If you're compiling for musl, why are you referencing glibc issues? The most obvious explanation is that that function is not implemented in musl. Except that it clearly is: see the arch-specific directories in https://git.musl-libc.org/cgit/musl/tree/src/signal

Comment: rust library is compiled in musl and the cpp program that is calling the library is glibc. Yes I know it's bad, nothing to do about it - and glibc is complaining, not musl - the library compiles fine

Comment: You can't use a musl-compiled library in a glibc-compiled program (nor the other way round). Your program and all the libraries it uses must use the same libc.

Comment: I already use one lib like that. Propably i god lucky to not make any conflicts then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glibc (in past at least) did not have the function `sigsetjmp`. It had a macro defined conditionally like

```
#ifdef __USE_POSIX
# define sigsetjmp(env, savemask) __sigsetjmp (env, savemask)
#endif
```

You either do not `#include <setjmp.h>` somewhere and the compiler uses the implicitly declared `int sigsetjmp()`, or the macro `__USE_POSIX` is not defined while compiling the C code in the file armcap.c.

If that does not fix the issue, you can define your own `int sigsetjmp(sigjmp_buf env, int savemask)` like in this topic:
[undefined reference to `siglongjmp' error when compiling android cocos2dx project for x86 architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14808884/undefined-reference-to-siglongjmp-error-when-compiling-android-cocos2dx-projec).

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution - I ended up flushing the code using this in openssl